# wordpress MU / network share the wp_options table between all sites

Tags: wordpress, networking, mu

When setting up a "network" (previously an MU install) several new tables are created.

```
wp_3_commentmeta
wp_3_comments
wp_3_links
wp_3_options
wp_3_postmeta
wp_3_posts
wp_3_terms
wp_3_term_relationships
wp_3_term_taxonomy
```

What if you wanted to share the wp_options table amoungst all of your sites so that the same roles, admin settings, themes would be stored and managed all in the same place.

You could also manually copy all these settings into the new table but that seems like a heck of alot of unnescary coding.

Can you toggle whether a subsite uses it's own table or the parent table?

Can't seem to find this answer anywhere, any help would be greatly appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use the Cloned Sites for WPMU plugin to create the sites with the same options. It doesn't help so much if you need to sync them all going forward, but it might be what you need:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-cloned-sites-for-wpmu-batch/

Comment: Thanks wryteowl that was very helpful. I ended up just using PHP myadmin to migrate the tables I wanted.. and now I can use this plug-in to "clone" this setup for any new sites I create. THANKS!